# How to count number of days between two dates using <time.h>

Tags: c, time.h

I'm trying to code a c function that calculates de number of DAYS between two dates ( format: yyyy-mm-dd ) using time.h.

The date is read from a string. 
I don't need to account for seconds or minutes.

I know I probably need to use difftime() but how can It be used in that format?

Thank you,

---

This is what I tried to do but I get segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CURRDATE "2019-10-5"
#define OTHER "2019-10-10"

void auxDate(struct tm *t, char *date)
{
    struct tm p;

    p.tm_year = atoi(strtok(date, "-")) - 1900;
    p.tm_mon = atoi(strtok(date, "-"));
    p.tm_mday = atoi(date);

    *t = p;
}
int main()
{
    struct tm date1, date2;

    auxDate(&date1, CURRDATE);
    auxDate(&date2, OTHER);

    printf("%.0lf\n", difftime(mktime(&date1), mktime(&date2)));
}
```

Comment: Are you on a platform that supports POSIX `strptime()`?

Comment: Could you post what you tried?

Comment: please post what you've tried to do, people here don't solve your problem, they help you learn how to solve it yourself

Comment: There are some open-source programs out on the Internet that do this. Perhaps reviewing the source code for them will help give some ideas to you.

Comment: No, I dont believe my platform supports strptime().

Comment: Your usage of `strtok()` is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Code fails for various reasons.

`"2019-10-5"` is a *string literal* that `strtok(date, "-")` attempts to modify. This leads to *undefined behavior* (UB).  Certainly the cause of the segmentation fault.

Instead use `void auxDate(struct tm *t, const char *date)` and parse `date` without attempting to change it.  See `strspn()` and `strcspn()`.

---

`mktime(&date1)` uses a not completely assigned `struct tm`.  Initialize all `struct tm` members with `struct tm p = { 0 };`.  Otherwise the uninitialized members can provide erroneous values to `mktime()`.

---

`.tm_mon` is the number of month *since* January.  I'd expect a `- 1` somewhere.

---

Since `difftime()` return the difference in seconds and the goal is difference in days. Division by the seconds-per-day is missing.

---

The are other corner case to solve that involve daylight savings time and redefinitions of a timezone's offset that will shift the time differences by a hour or so.

To handle, code could use the time at noon and set the DST to -1

```
p.tm_hour = 12;
p.tm_isdst = -1;
```

Then round the division:

```
days = round(difftime(...)/(24.0*60*60));
```

Even this will not handle very rare cases when a Pacific area timezone changed which side of the international date line it was on, which effectively repeated or cancelled a day.

---

On the good side, your posted code does compile.